# Created a two condition While loop, one condition works as should the other causes an infinite loop

Tags: java

so im still new to java programming and for this program i need to make a program that calculates change for a vending machine. It is based of a 5 cent increment between a value of 25 cents to a dollar. for this assignment if i use a loop to force the user to input a value in bounds i get extra credit, since i originally was going to scratch because i wasnt getting it but soon did im back to using it. only thing is for one of my conditions it creates an infinite loop of the output message and im not sure why. any advice would be appreciated

```
/** Carmine A
The purpose of this program is to calculate the change to be dispensed from 
a vending machine */


//import scanner so user can input data
import java.util.Scanner;

public class lab2Test{

//declaration of variables to be used in program


float changeGiven;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
    //ties user input variable to class so scanner can use it
    int userInput;
    int itemCost;

        //initiates the keyboard to be used
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        //print statement to tell user how to enter price
        System.out.println("Enter price of item from 25 cents to a dollar in 5-cent increments \n"
                        + "Do not enter a decimal point");

    //user inputs value to be set to variable
    userInput= keyboard.nextInt();
    //System.out.println("You entered ." +userInput + " as the price");

    //while loop to make sure input stays in bounds
    while(userInput<25 || userInput>100){
        System.out.println("Invalid amount entered! \n"
                        + "Please enter an amount between 25 cents and 1 dollar");

                while(userInput>25 && userInput<100){
                System.out.println("Price is in bounds");
                System.out.println("Please enter a valid amount between 25-100");
                itemCost=keyboard.nextInt();
            }
}
itemCost=userInput;
//print out item cost based off users input
System.out.println("You enetered: " + itemCost +" as the items cost");
```

}
}

*update*

ok took what you guys said and made this

```
//while loop to make sure input stays in bounds
    while(userInput<25 || userInput>100){
        System.out.println("Invalid amount entered! \n"
                        + "Please enter an amount between 25 cents and 1 dollar");
        userInput=keyboard.nextInt();

                        }
```

thanks for the help! knew it was something dumb, but this is why i ask for help so i can learn

so i believe it is frowned upon if i made another thread for the same program so i will add to this one.

i have completed just about everything i need but am having a few issues.
1. for some reason after i compile and run my code "Change Due:" prints twice, i am unsure why since i only have it once in a print statement but i can be missing it.
2.i need to print out in a money format and for some reason i have tried different formatting options and none will round (i have a feeling it is but it is not displaying because of the second "Change due:" printing) but can be wrong
3. on line 55 i am receiving this message and not sure why C:\Users\finst\Desktop\Intro to Java\Labs\Lab2\lab2Test.java:55: error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to int
    changeRemainder= (changeDue*(double)100);

this is what i currently have:
    /** Carmine 
    The purpose of this program is to calculate the change to be dispensed from 
    a vending machine */

```
//import scanner so user can input data
import java.util.Scanner;

public class lab2Test{

//declaration of variables to be used in program

    public static void main(String args[]) {
    //ties user input variable to class so scanner can use it
    double userInput;
    double itemCost;

        //initiates the keyboard to be used
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        //print statement to tell user how to enter price
        System.out.println("Enter price of item from 25 cents to a dollar in 
5-cent increments");


    //user inputs value to be set to variable
    userInput= keyboard.nextDouble();

    //while loop to make sure input stays in bounds
    while(userInput<(.25) || userInput>(1.00)){
        System.out.println("Invalid amount entered! \n"
                        + "Please enter an amount between 25 cents and 1 
dollar");
        userInput=keyboard.nextDouble();

                        }


//print out item cost based off users input
System.out.println("You entered: " + userInput +" as the items cost");
System.out.println("You entered a dollar to pay with");

//algorithm to calculate change due
int quarters;
int nickels;
int dimes;
int pennies;
int changeRemainder;
double changeDue;
double dollar=1;

//calculates change due
changeDue= (dollar - userInput);
//System.out.printf("%.2f" + "\n" ,changeDue);
//System.out.println("Change due:" + changeDue);

//makes the remainder into a number that can be used
changeRemainder= (changeDue*(double)100);

//calculates the amount of each coin needed to make the change
quarters= (changeRemainder / 25);
changeRemainder= changeRemainder % 25;

dimes= (changeRemainder/10);
changeRemainder= changeRemainder%10;

nickels=(changeRemainder/5);
changeRemainder= changeRemainder%5;

pennies=(changeRemainder);

//output statement to print coin amounts
System.out.println("Quarters: " + quarters);
System.out.println("Dimes: " + dimes);
System.out.println("Nickels: " + nickels);
System.out.println("Pennies: " + pennies);
```

}
}

Comment: ok took what you guys said and made this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `userInput` is never updated in the loop then its value does not change and it will potentially loop for ever.

Maybe you mean `userInput=keyboard.nextInt();`  but you do not need two loops anyway.

```
userInput=keyboard.nextInt();
while (userInput<25 || userInput>100) {
    System.out.println("Invalid amount entered! \n"
                    + "Please enter an amount between 25 cents and 1 dollar");
    userInput=keyboard.nextInt();
}
```

Comment: yaa, that was sorta my next thing i had to figure out, i wasn't sure how to prompt to enter a proper amount again after the wrong amount is entered, i have an idea of it but it didnt get far due to the loop

Comment: i added another question, if you could take a peek would appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

You don't need 2 while loops; just one will do. In any case, your while loop checks the 'userInput' variable, but that never changes in the while loop; you are updating the itemCost variable instead.

Comment: now that you bring that up i can delete it, i made the second while loop because originally my first one did not work because i used && instead of || so ill take that one out

Answer (score 0):

I would use a Boolean for your while loop, and create an if else statement within this to check for valid entry and calculate the change. Hope this helps!

```
boolean end = true;
while (end) {
   //retrieve user input of cost and assign value to variable 

   //create an if statement check if the value is valid
   if(itemCost >=25 && itemCost <=100){

      //retrieve user input for change entered

      //calculate change for the user and display it

      //end loop
      end = false;
   } else {  
      //invalid entry
      end = false;
   }
}
```

Comment: i appreciate the response, i used the other method i posted, also my prof. does not want us using end to end our loops in that way so  i wouldnt be able to use that method